# How to pass the value to next page dropdown?

Tags: java, jsf

I am having list of values in the datatable and click the one row link it will go to another page dropdown as current value and as well as need to send backend for the value.

After that if i change the dropdown value again need to get and send it to back end for retrive the values.

I am using jsf and java1.6.How to do do that ? Could you please give me your sugestions ...

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the value to a bean property and access the same bean property in the next page.